# populating data frame col with the lookedup matching value of a column in another data frame

Tags: r, syntax, indexing, lookup

I've got an indexing puzzle.  Here is the toy version.  I have a lookup df, HasCats, with 2 cols, Uid and Cats, which gives me, for each Uid,  the category grouping of that Uid.    I have another df, NeedsCats,  that needs this category attribute info added to it in a new column, according to the value of Uid.   Uid will repeat in NeedsCats.

```
NeedsCats <- data.frame("Uid" = c("B", "D", "A", "C", "C"))
HasCats <- data.frame("Uid" = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), "Cat" = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "bb"))
```

I'm looking for the right assignment statement that will populate NeedsCats$Cats with the correct values, the lookedup value in HasCats, of each value for $Uid in NeedsCats, in this case, c("bb", "bb", "aa", "aa", "aa").

NeedsCats is quite long, and Uid values will repeat and can occur in any order.

I'm having trouble figuring how to do this in a vectorised way that exploits R indexing properly.   I think it's probably very simple.   Can someone help?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example try `merge`:

```
merge(NeedsCats, HasCats)
#   Uid Cat
# 1   A  aa
# 2   B  bb
# 3   C  aa
# 4   C  aa
# 5   D  bb

# or to avoid re-ordering
merge(NeedsCats, HasCats, sort = FALSE)

# for some reason the 'no sorting please' in merge rarely works for more complex merging
# if order is important, and you don't want to re-order using `order` you may try:
library(plyr)
join(NeedsCats, HasCats)
# Joining by: Uid
#   Uid Cat
# 1   B  bb
# 2   D  bb
# 3   A  aa
# 4   C  aa
# 5   C  aa
```

Comment: Glad that you found my answer helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've just kludged something up that seems to work....  I turn the Uids in HasCats into row names, then index into HasCats based on these labels, using the values of NeedsCats that need matching, specifying the column for the lookedup value numerically.

```
rownames(HasCats) <- HasCats$Uid
NeedsCats$Cat <- HasCats[NeedsCats$Uid, 2]
```

Is this actually a sensible way of going about this, or is there a something more obvious that I've missed?

thanks!

Comment: this actually doesn't work on my real data set - !  I've muddled up the indexing..... (something like it will probably work though...)